# Not able to find TFS 2013 Project email alerts

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

Some people in my company are getting build failure alerts, I have searched the same in alerts explorer with build administrator account and not finding any build alerts.

Please help me if I need to look anywhere else to see all the build alerts.

**EDIT:**

I can currently see 3 build alerts when I connect with build administrator account and all of them are related to individual accounts. But still some bunch of people are receiving only build failure alerts who's id's are not mentioned in the email alerts list.

[image]

The 5 build alerts have individual email id's. Not sure why tfs is sending build failure email notifications to many people.

Answer (score 1):

On Visual Studio go:

Team Explorer -> Settings (img1) -> Project Alerts (img 2)

And then you can choose the email alerts you want (img 3).

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can also go in "Advanced Settings" and see the personal Alerts, the Team Alerts, where you can check the email addresses used.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The 5 build alerts  (please see screenshot ,i have added it in my previous reply) are configured with individual email id's.

Comment: all the 5 alerts have email to individual id's none of them are Distribution lists. Is there any chance the alert was created and deleted but was not reflected in TFS database. Is there a way to check email notification through sql query to tfs database

Answer (score 0):

Not really. But you can look in the tbl_subscription table. However DO NOT edit that table directly or you loose support. You can use bissubscribe.exe to explicitly delete subscriptions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx